# How to lazy load images using intersection observer?

Tags: javascript

I have implemented this intersection observer to have images fade in as they enter the viewport. However, when the page is reloaded the images still load in immediately even though they aren't in the viewport. Does intersection observer have the ability to lazy load these images?

```
JavaScript code:

    'use strict';
    
    
    
    const faders = document.querySelectorAll('.fade-in');
    
    const appearOptions = {
        threshold: 0.4
    
    };
    const appearOnScroll = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, appearOnScroll) {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            if (!entry.isIntersecting) return;
            else {
                entry.target.classList.add('appear');
                appearOnScroll.unobserve(entry.target);
    
            }
        })
    }, appearOptions);

faders.forEach(fader => {
    appearOnScroll.observe(fader);
})
```

Comment: "when the page is reloaded the images still load in immediately"
You're just toggling the class so nothing stops the browser from fetching the images

Comment: @RameshReddy I know. I am wondering if you can implement lazy loading with an intersection observer; does intersection observer have this ability I am unaware of? I have tried to figure out how to lazy load, and adding loading = "lazy" in the html code on the image tags does not work (I've seen this as suggested solution)

Comment: You can assign the `src` attribute when they intersect to load the images lazily.

Comment: @RameshReddy so when they intersect, that is when the src attribute is assigned? So I should delete the src in the html markup and assign the src of the images using JavaScript?

Comment: Yes. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the actual image source to a data attribute and set it back to `src` when the image intersects the viewport.

Run the below snippet and scroll down:

```js
const img = document.querySelector('img');

const io = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (!entry.isIntersecting) return;
    entry.target.src = entry.target.getAttribute('data-src');
    io.unobserve(entry.target);
  })
});

io.observe(img);
```

```css
.space {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="space"></div>
<img alt="I'm lazy" data-src="https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/pug/n02110958_7255.jpg" />
```

Comment: Awesome solution, thank you. This makes since because the image isn't getting assigned a source until its in the viewport, which means it can't load unless it is in fact inside the viewport.